# How to create test_endpoint?

Tags: 7, services

I am new to drupal and I am  using  services module for using REST   and  RESTWS module. I used RESTWS and could get the content of the node by  http://base_url/node/1.xml and now I need to add a node and users from my external PHP application in to  drupal. I googled and I found here that we need to use http://base_drupal_url/drupal7/test_endpoint/users . I tried to create a service from Drupal 7, but I dont know what should I give on endpoint title ,name and endpoint path and I assume I need to give the same endpoint path in the curl.

Any help as to how to check if rest server is installed and how to create endpoint path would be of great help.

I am using Drupal 7 with services  module services-7.x-3.0-rc3

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have created an endpoint and resource path exactly as you but I am getting "Not Found The requested URL /~DrupalWorkstation/Drupal/drupal_7_16/rest/node was not found on this server." error. Please check my comment to the highest voted answer. Let me know if you have a solution for this.

Answer (score 56):

Services module is easy to use, but it can be tricky to configure especially if you are new to the concept. So,  I am going to post the screenshots to make configuration of Services modules easy for "Drupal Answers" users.

**Following is the version of Services module installed on my machine:**

[image]

**Create an endpoint called 'rest' as shown below:**

[image]

**Select the type of server and endpoint path:**

[image]

**Select the list of resources that you want to enable and specify aliases:**

[image]

**Select the response formatters and request parsers that you want to enable:**

[image]

**You can test your configuration as shown below:**

[image]

**You can get the list of all nodes as below:**

[image]

**And specific node as:**

[image]

Following are the excellent examples scripts provided by [MichaelCole](http://drupal.org/user/8121) here http://drupal.org/node/910598#comment-4677738 to create nodes from any external PHP application.

I am duplicating his code for completeness of this answer.

```
//--------------login to the server------------------------
$service_url = 'http://example.dev/rest/user/login.xml'; // .xml asks for xml data in response
$post_data = array(
    'username' => 'test',
    'password' => 'test',
);
$post_data = http_build_query($post_data, '', '&'); // Format post data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded
// set up the request
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  // have curl_exec return a string

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);             // do a POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); // POST this data
// make the request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); // output to command line
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print "LOGIN RESPONSE:\n";
var_dump($response);



// parse the response
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$session_cookie = $xml->session_name . '=' . $xml->sessid;
// print "SESSION_COOKIE: $session_cookie";

file_put_contents('session_cookie.txt', $session_cookie);

//----------------create a node -------------------------------

$node_data = array(
    'type' => 'ct_metadata_core',
    'title' => 'test layer',
    'field_core_lat_n[und][0]' => array('value' => '90'),
    'field_core_lat_s[und][0]' => array('value' => '-90'),
    'field_core_long_e[und][0]' => array('value' => '180'),
    'field_core_long_w[und][0]' => array('value' => '-180'),
    'field_core_description[und][0]' => array('value' => 'National Data Buoy Center'),
    'field_core_originator[und][0]' => array('value' => 'NDBC'),
    'field_core_url[und][0]' => array('url' => 'http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/kml/marineobs_as_kml.php?sort=pgm'),
    'field_cont_res_name_org[und][0]' => array('value' => 'test'),

);


$service_url = 'http://example.dev/rest/node'; // .xml asks for xml data in response
$session_cookie = file_get_contents('session_cookie.txt');

$node_data = http_build_query($node_data, '', '&'); // Format post data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded
// set up the request
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  // have curl_exec return a string

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "$session_cookie"); // use the previously saved session

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);             // do a POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $node_data); // POST this data
// make the request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); // output to command line
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print "CREATE NODE RESPONSE:\n";
var_dump($response);


//----------------logout from the server-------------------------

$service_url = 'http://example.dev/rest/user/logout';
$session_cookie = file_get_contents('session_cookie.txt');

// set up the request
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  // have curl_exec return a string

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "$session_cookie"); // use the previously saved session
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);             // do a POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ""); // POST this data
// make the request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); // output to command line
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print "LOGOUT RESPONSE:\n";
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: So worth pointing out that he enabled *every* request parsing option. I wasted a lot of time before I realized that "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is disabled by default.

Comment: where do I have to write the above code snippet? Is it inside modules/services/server/rest_server/lib?

Comment: @subhojit777 above code is a stand alone PHP code snippet that can be used to consume services api hosted on an external server, and you can write it in you module file, but writing it in modules/services/server/rest_server/lib is probably not the best place.

Comment: I have setup everything as you said on my localhost. I have a path to my drupal site running as: http://localhost/~DrupalWorkstation/Drupal/drupal_7_16/. The index.php page is running when I hit above URL, but my configured endpoint and resource path would not work. My URL to trigger the service is: http://localhost/~DrupalWorkstation/Drupal/drupal_7_16/rest/node. I get the following error: "Not Found

The requested URL /~DrupalWorkstation/Drupal/drupal_7_16/rest/node was not found on this server." Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Arigato gozaimasu Ajinkya sensei. ARIGATO!!!

Comment: Tip: Make sure that the rest_server module is enabled so that "REST" is an option selectable from menu for the mandatory Server field when adding a service via admin/structure/services/add . rest_server module comes with services (e.g. 7.x-3.17 at time of writing 2016 12 29)

Comment: Tip 2 (part1): When you want to use your URL from externally bear in mind that the "path to endpoint" precedes the path defined in your Services-based Display for your View (look for the path settings in the centre column of the View Display editor ( `admin/structure/views/view/<your view machine name>/edit/<your services-based view display machine name>` )  in your Display that your created in your View that was based on Services). Your "path to endpoint" is defined in the Configuration for Settings for your endpoint `admin/structure/services/list/<your end point machine name>`

Comment: Tip 2 (part 2) So if your endpoint path is abc and your path in your Services View Display is  xyz. Then the full URL for external use would be: http://myserver.com/abc/xyz

Comment: Tip 3 (part 1 of 2): you will only see the output in XML when you use the external URL. The preview within the View edit screen only shows an array-like structured output. Want JSON instead of XML outputted? :- How to get services / services_views to output JSON for your View: simply add `.json` to the end of the external URL path (I found this to work). So if you have : `myserver.com/abc/xyz` - which outputs XML, then : `myserver.com/abc/xyz.json` will output JSON.

Comment: Tip 3 (part 2 of 2) Note: make sure that JSON is enabled in the settings for the endpoint, in the Services config, go to admin/structure/services then find your endpoint in the list, from the operations, click 'edit server' - direct path: `admin/structure/services/list/<your endpoint machine name>/server` on this page make sure that JSON is enabled.

Comment: Issue - missing field data: I'm noticing some fields output (in both XML and JSON) are empty - the datatype is array (e.g. for fields that take multiple taxonomy values or list options). Services/Services Views seem like mature stable modules so hoping that the issue I'm seeing is because I have not completed my configuration (or done it incorrectly). Can you advise?

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you read [Creating a resource for Services 3.x](http://drupal.org/node/783460).

Also, I'm note sure if Services and RESTWS are compatible; they both offer variations of the same thing, and as such may conflict.

Comment: I would like to know what should i give in the endpoint path in the service add option in drupal 7

Comment: and should i write any custom code in drupal   to create a node from my php application?

Comment: Services has built in resources that can be used. regarding RestWS and compatability: There's a port of RestWS to Services that was rejected by the RestWS maintainers. If anyone is interested it could be published as a separate module though.