# Services Module - Access Denied for User Admin

Tags: services, 8

I'm trying to get a REST server going with Services, testing locally. It seems like things are running, but I'm denied from using any of the resources, even as an admin!

I'm trying to follow the simple directions [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4718/how-to-create-test-endpoint). My endpoint is 'test', I've enabled the node resource and session authentication. When I visit something like localhost/test/node or localhost/test/node/1, I get back an xml snippet:

```
<result>Access denied for user admin</result>
```

Clearly I'm hitting the service. I'm able to view the node the normal way (visiting localhost/node/1).

I'm quite confused, and have a hell of a time searching for answers. There are lots of people with issues authenticating using services, but none like this. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

---

It works on my site. Still no joy on localhost. It may be due to document root - see the post by yuchuan1 on February 5, 2013 at 6:44am [here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/173324).

Comment: Having the same problem `access denied for user root` (WTF?), but I'm not on localhost, so there has to be an issue with the webserver configuration!