# Problems with Services and CSRF token

Tags: 7, users, services, csrf

I've been trying to create a user via webservice without doing any custom coding or curl.
This post got me 75% there: [How to create test_endpoint?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4718/how-to-create-test-endpoint)

I finally got it working, but only by passing in my creds with each request.  CSRF token header is ignored.

I'm using the Services and Services basic authentication modules.

I do an initial GET request to services/session/token with Basic auth headers with my username/password and get the token as expected.
In the next call, POST to rest/user, I have the CSRF token (HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN) and Content-type (application/json) and json encoded user data in the body.  Instead of authenticating with the token, I get a login popup.

If instead I send the Basic auth headers with my username/password along with the create user request and json data, it works.  I don't understand why CSRF is being ignored.

Thoughts?

Edit:  One other note.  In testing I used both the FF RestClient and FF Poster plugins.  I have not tested on Chrome.

Comment: The header needs to be named `X-CSRF-Token`, not `HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN`

Comment: Thanks Clive.  I added the solution to my original post for future users.

Answer (score 3):

For future users, there's a bunch of confusing examples out there. Based on the above link example this is my working setup:

URL: /rest/user.json

Headers:

```
"X-CSRF-Token":"fsddfhbusoibdfbdsbfoubewbfw"
"Content-Type":"application/json"
```

Body:

```
{
 "name":"username",
 "pass":"password",
 "mail":"email",
 "field_user_full_name":{"und":[{"value":"CHECK1 n CHECK2"}]},
 "roles":[4],
 "status":"1",
 "language":"und"
}
```

Comment: Is this for sending multiple values, like an unlimited field?