# REST Services module - Access denied for user anonymous

Tags: 7, services

I'm Using `Drupal 7`, I installed `Services` module with all the requirements, according to this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4718/how-to-create-test-endpoint) and this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xv19Li5OaEg).
[image]

I'm trying to get all users with Postman where I give my credential, but I'm getting back that I'm an anonymous user.

[image]

1. How do I pass my credentials?
2. How to add a filter to that call ,for example get all users with specific role?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, wrote my own module

Comment: Well i also follow this  but i unable to login is there any way to do  this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the user login who have the permission to view the list of user details using following Service API

```
http://yourdomain/endpointname/user/login
```

with follwing json data as arguments

```
{
"username":"username of the user who have the permission to view the users list",
"password":"password which matched with username"
}
```

After the successful login you need to get the CSRF token which will play the key role in all authenticated request. To get the token call the below mentioned API,

```
http://yourdomain/endpointname/user/token
```

You will receive a token, then add the token to your postman header for the key named **X_CSRF_TOKEN**. Then you can start to make the authenticated requests.

Answer (score 1):

As per latest changes...
Please follow this [thread](http://tylerfrankenstein.com/user/4/code/drupal-services-examples).

And most important **token key** should be **X-CSRF-Token**.

It can be achieved from below URL also.

```
http://somehost/services/session/token
```

Answer (score 1):

Worth mentioning that now you'd also have to set the following header:

```
Name     Value
Cookie   [session_name]=[sessid]
```

You'll be finding the values for session_name and sessid in the login response, right before the token-value for your X-CSRF-Token.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to list your users you should create a view in drupal and choose the type to display as users. You can't show lists otherwise from the rest api unless you first create a view to display the list. The other points only let you create,edit, or delete them.