# How to make getTree works?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, services

I want to expose a vocabulary to an external server using services module. I have followed this question [How to create test_endpoint](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4718/how-to-create-test-endpoint), and checked every checkbox, and enabled the `REST Server Module.

The only endpoint that I interest is `getTree`. But I don't know how to compose the URL. I can't find any document describing the detail (please tell me if you know).

1. Which HTTP method should I use? GET or POST? I think it should be a GET, but I got nothing
2. how to specify the vid? /taxonomy_vocabulary/[vid]/getTree ? /taxonomy_vocabulary/getTree/[vid] ? or /taxonomy_vocabulary/getTree?vid=[vid]? any other params?

I have try some URL,

`GET  [endpoint]/taxonomy_vocabulary/getTree` will response `[false]` (what is this mean?)

`POST [endpoint]/taxonomy_vocabulary/getTree` will response `401 Unauthorized`, but whatever I disable or enable the Session Authorization, I got the same response.

Answer (score 2):

you must add {"vid":"1234"} in the body of HTTP POST request and add Content-Type in the header request with "application/json"